# Char Sequence vs Regex

Tags: java

```
txt.replaceAll("a","b");
```

Is `"a"` a Char Sequence or a Regex (or more specific Literal Search)?

And is my code correct? 
I’m coding the Exercise "Normalize Text".
Task:

- Only one space between words.
- Only one space after comma (,), dot (.) and colon (:). First
  character of word after dot is in Uppercase and other words are in
  lower case.

---

Please correct me if I am wrong, including my English.

```
public class NormalizeText {

    static String spacesBetweenWords(String txt){
        txt = txt.replaceAll(" +", " ");
        return txt;
    }

    /**
     * - There are no spaces between comma or dot and word in front of it. 
     * - Only one space after comma (,), dot (.) and colon (:).
     */
    static String spacesCommaDotColon(String txt) {
        txt = txt.replaceAll(" +\\.", ".");
        txt = txt.replaceAll(" +,", ",");
        txt = txt.replaceAll(" +[:]", ":");
        txt = txt.replaceAll("[.]( *)", ". ");
        txt = txt.replaceAll("[,]( *)", ", ");
        txt = txt.replaceAll("[:]( *)", ": ");
        //txt.replaceAll("a","b");

        return txt;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String txt = "\" \\\"     i want to   f\\\"ly\"  .  B.ut :  I   ,     Cant\\";
        System.out.println(txt);
        txt = spacesBetweenWords(txt);
        System.out.println(spacesBetweenWords(txt));
        System.out.println(spacesCommaDotColon(txt));
    }

}
```

My teacher said my code is not using regex, but rather a Char Sequence. 
I am very confused.

Comment: technically "a" is a regex (albeit a trivial regex) and a character sequence.  I think your professor is trying to get you to use a more complicated regex, instead of a sequence of trivial ones.

Comment: If you do not want to use regex you would use `txt.replace("a","b");` instead of `replaceAll`, `replaceAll` is _always_ regex.  Note that `replace` still replaces all occurrences.

Comment: Are you asking about the method? Or your method call?

Comment: Raedwald: the spacesCommaDotColon(); Method

Comment: @Gus your comment is the answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters because you learn how to user regex, an amazing site to learn how to use regex is [this](https://regex101.com/). 
Now `replaceAll` first argument counts as regex. Just the letter "a" is a regex matching only the "a" inside the text. So what your teacher meant is probably to use a more complicated regex ( something to match multiple cases at once). 
As this is an exercise I prefer not to give a solution so you will try to figure it out by yourself. The tip is try to use `replaceAll` only once.! Or the closer you can get to once.

As for your code if its correct. It seems good but you are missing the uppercase after the dots condition. 
Also because I said try to use only one `replaceAll` the solution for the uppercase doesn't count as it requires an other approach.

I hope I helped and you will find a solution to the exercise and again sorry for not providing an answer to the exercise but In my opinion you need to try to figure it out on your own. You are already on a good road!

Comment: @Amessihel your answer is not wrong just not on the teaching spec that this question seem to have, same as the followup comments :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Also, you could perform dot, comma and colon formatting with one call using capturing groups:

```
static String spacesCommaDotColon(String txt) {
    return txt.replaceAll("\\s*([.,:])\\s*", "$1 ");
}
```

Explanation:

- **`"\\s*([.,:])\\s*"`**: **look** for a comma, dot or colon character with any surrounding blank character; **capture** said character (parenthesis captures matched text)
- **`"$1 "`**: **replace** the matched text by the captured character (labelled as `$1` since it's was caught by the first and uniq capturing parenthesis) and one space

---

Another solution given by TEXHIK, using look-ahead:

```
txt.replaceAll("(?<=[,.:])\s{2,}", "");
```

Which looks for any set of at least two blank character preceded by a comma, a dot or a colon and remove it. Maybe not something to see before understanding regex basis.

Comment: It is also possible to use look-behind, java regex supports it as I know:
`txt.replaceAll("(?<=[,.:])\s{2,}", "");` Add it to your answer to have all ways in one place.

Comment: Yes, I can, but I usually don't read other answers after one, that covers my case and have good formatting and explanation. So not all well see this way in my answer

Answer (score 0):

With regards to `replaceAll`, the docs say:

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.
>
> An invocation of this method of the form *`str`*`.replaceAll(`*`regex`*`,` *`repl`*`)` yields exactly the same result as the expression
>
> `Pattern.compile(`*`regex`*`).matcher(`*`str`*`).replaceAll(`*`repl`*`)`

Therefore, `replaceAll` will always use regular expressions for its first parameter. With regards to simplifying your code,

```
static String spacesCommaDotColon(String txt) {
    txt = txt.replaceAll(" +\\.", ".");
    txt = txt.replaceAll(" +,", ",");
    txt = txt.replaceAll(" +[:]", ":");
    txt = txt.replaceAll("[.]( *)", ". ");
    txt = txt.replaceAll("[,]( *)", ", ");
    txt = txt.replaceAll("[:]( *)", ": ");
    //txt.replaceAll("a","b");

    return txt;
}
```

can be simplified to:

```
static String spacesCommaDotColon(String txt) {
    return txt.replaceAll(" *([:,.]) *","$2 ");
}
```

and

```
static String spacesBetweenWords(String txt){
    txt = txt.replaceAll(" +", " ");
    return txt;
}
```

can be simplified to:

```
static String spacesBetweenWords(String txt){
    return txt.replaceAll(" +", " ");
}
```